# Data filtering by creating dictionaries in python

Tags: python, data-manipulation

I am trying to assign keys and values to each position in a sequence using a reference file such as below.

```
NC_000932.1 RefSeq  exon    527 551 .   +   .   ID=exon-ArthCt098-1;Parent=rna-ArthCt098;Dbxref=GeneID:1466263;gbkey=tRNA;gene=trnT
NC_000932.1 RefSeq  CDS 554 570 .   +   0   ID=cds-NP_051054.1;Parent=gene-ArthCp017;Dbxref=Genbank:NP_051054.1,GeneID:844775;Name=NP_051054.1;gbkey=CDS;gene=psbD
NC_000932.1 RefSeq  CDS 610 612 .   +   0   ID=cds-NP_051055.1;Parent=gene-ArthCp018;Dbxref=Genbank:NP_051055.1,GeneID:844773;Name=NP_051055.1;Note=CP43;gbkey=CDS;gene=psbC
```

I wanted to define a range of numbers (or count with while loop), and give each number a value according to the reference.
So the script should search for the intervals in 4th and 5th columns and between that interval assigning each number as a key and 3rd column for respective values.

My desired output is below;

```
    "1": "na"
    "2": "na"
    "3": "na"
    .
    .
    "526": "na"
    "527": "exon"
    "528": "exon"
    "529": "exon"
    .
    .
    .
    "550": "exon"
    "551": "exon"
    "552": "na"
    "553": "na"
    "554": "exon"
    "555": "exon"
    .
    .
    .
   "570":"exon"
   "571":"na"
   .
   .
   .
    "610": "na"
    "611": "CDS"
    "612": "CDS"
    .
    .
    .
    until the range ends.
```

I believe a while loop with a count is the correct way, but I am failing to end it correctly and it goes into an endless loop. I tried directly assigning the values as strings but I realize library is what I need because the data is too big to handle. I would be glad if you can show a way to solve this.

The script I was working is below, I was trying with printing to check the values.

```
import os

os.chdir("dir")

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as f:

    lines = []
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)

    lines = [x.rstrip() for x in lines]

    #print(lines)

    count = 1
    position_start = 0
    position_end = 0
    
    
    for i in range(1, 154478):

        while position_end < 154478:
            position_start += int(lines[i].split('\t')[3])
            position_end += int(lines[i].split('\t')[4])
            
            if lines[i].split('\t')[2] == 'exon':

                
                
                print("g" + str(count) + ' exon ' +  lines[i].split('\t')[8].split(';')[2].split('=')[1] + ' ' + str(position_start) + ' ' + str(position_end))

            elif lines[i].split('\t')[2] == 'CDS':

                print("g" + str(count) + ' CDS ' +  lines[i].split('\t')[8].split(';')[2].split('=')[1] + ' ' + str(position_start) + ' ' + str(position_end))

            position_end += 1
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you have written so far?

Comment: Sorry I forgot it.